# use JAVA APIs in Firebreath

Tags: java, c++

I want to develop a cross Browser Plugin in Firebreath using JAVA APIs. How in Firebreath, which is in C++,can i use JAVA APIs.

- One way was to convert JAVA Project to C++ via JNI but to convert so many files is there any simpler way?
- Or any other way by which I can give the reference of JAVA APIs in Firebreath.

Comment: Is there any reason why you'd want to do this? If you tell us why people may be able to suggest a better solution.

Comment: Suggestion to clarify your question: are you trying to access functionality that you already have in Java from a C++ application, or is it essential that you convert your codebase to C++? Is it also essential that your codebase be maintainable after this conversion or is spaghetti machine-generated C++ acceptable? What's the underlying motivation for this?

Comment: Hi I need to use the functionality of Java but not thru JNI . is there any other way

Answer (score 3):

No.

The syntax of C++ and Java is similar but it is not the same and the libraries used are very different. If you want to port you will need to do it by hand.